# jQuery: how to add an element after a text node?

Tags: jquery

Say I have the following markup:

```
<h1>Hello</h1>
```

and now, I want to add `<span id="foo" class="bar">world</span>` after `Hello` so that I have I have the resulting markup:

```
<h1>Hello<span id="foo" class="bar">world</span></h1>
```

How do I do this in jQuery?

Comment: I just drunkenly googled "jquery append html to node"

Comment: see the jsfidle example: http://jsfiddle.net/R5CpP/

Comment: Any proficient programmer knows what they want to do. You want to add html to an existing html element. It't not about what you know, it's about what you know to search for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$("h1").append( '<span id="foo" class="bar">world</span>' )
```

Answer (score 0):

**demo** http://jsfiddle.net/3zc3N/3/ few ways you can achieve this **or** http://jsfiddle.net/3zc3N/6/

**code**

```
$("h1").html($('h1').text() + ' <span id="foo" class="bar">world</span>');
```

or

the one above: http://jsfiddle.net/3zc3N/

```
$("h1").append(' <span id="foo" class="bar">world</span>');
```

Comment: Your first example is a low level example of what you're 2nd example does.

Comment: @Nick Yep I was thinking any business logic might need more then that < I reckon > - thats why `:)` just lil extra info innit!

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can do it simply by using .append statement i.e.

```
 $('#heading').append($('<span />').text(' World'));
```

as illustrated here http://jsfiddle.net/R5CpP/1/